# Einschub zwischen Komma und Gedankenstrich

Tags: punctuation

Noch ein Abschnitt aus *Parfum* von Patrick Süskind:

> Dann stellte er sich hinter Baldini, der noch immer mit bedächtiger
> Pedanterie seine Milchgefäße arrangierte, dieses Glas ein wenig dahin
> rückte, jenes noch ein wenig dorthin, damit alles seine gute
> altgewohnte Ordnung habe und sich im vorteilhaftesten Licht der
> Leuchter präsentiere – und wartete, zitternd vor Ungeduld, daß der
> Alte sich entferne und ihm Platz mache.

Meine Frage hier geht um den Gebrauch der Kombination von einem Komma und einem Gedankenstrich, um einen Einschub zu bilden. Im geschriebenen Englisch würde man zwei Striche verwenden, oder vielleicht zwei Kommas, um sowohl den Anfang als auch das Ende des Einschubs zu verdeutlichen, aber normalerweise keine Kombination. Im obigen Fall würde ich also im Englischen das vor "dieses" stehende Komma durch einen Strich ersetzen.

Wird diese Kombination auf Deutsch in der Regel benutzt? Darf man stattdessen zwei Striche benutzen, oder wäre das nicht üblich?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ich sehe da gar keinen Einschub, oder, wenn man es so verstehen möchte, nur von "dieses" bis "dorthin". Der "Damit"-Nebensatz bezieht sich ja schon wieder auf "arrangierte".

Ich würde hier eher den Gedankenstrich durch ein Komma ersetzen. Der Gedankenstrich dient hier nur dazu, aus dem langen Relativsatz samt von ihm abhängigem Nebensatz deutlich auszubrechen und in den Hauptsatz zurückzukehren.

Der Hauptsatz ist:

> Dann stellte er sich hinter Baldini *[Relativsatz]* und wartete [...].

Comment: Danke, ich verstehe jetzt, dass es keinen Einschub gibt, sondern einen Nebensatz. Wäre es jedenfalls besser, wie @Pollitzer vorschlägt, zwei Striche zu benutzen? Da ich englischer Muttersprachler bin, wirkt es ein bisschen verwirrend, eine solche Abschweifung mit einem Strich zu beenden aber ohne einen zu beginnen!

Answer (score 3):

Hier liegt aus meiner Sicht kein Einschub vor. Das Komma vor *dieses* gehört zu einer Aufzählung:

Baldini, der (1) noch immer mit bedächtiger Pedanterie seine Milchgefäße arrangierte, (2) dieses Glas ein wenig dahin rückte, (3) jenes noch ein wenig dorthin...

Der Gedankenstrich beendet daher keinen Einschub, sondern steht für eine Pause. Zusätzlich verdeutlicht der Gedankenstrich, dass das *und* nicht *präsentiere* und *wartete* verbindet, sondern *stellte* und *wartete*.

Answer (score 1):

Ich würde mich hier gar nicht auf den Begriff "Einschub" festlegen wollen. Dazu ist die Passage nach dem ersten Teilsatz (an diesen schließt strenggenommen der Teil ab dem Gedankenstrich an) zu lang. Der Gedankenstrich markiert quasi das Ende einer "allmählichen Abschweifung", der fiktive Erzähler ruft sich sozusagen selbst zur Ordnung und fährt damit fort, die Handlung zu schildern. Damit liegt auch **nur hier** eine Zäsur, die der Gedankenstrich markiert. Der Lesefluss wird unterbrochen, ohne dass exakt gesgt werden kann, wo er anschließt (technisch: erster Halbsatz; erzählerisch: zweiter / dritter Halbsatz?).

Answer (score 1):

Ich sehe auch keinen Einschub, würde aber einen einbauen, würde das Komma nach »Baldini« durch einen Gedankenstrich ersetzen. Grund: Der lange Relativsatz schreit geradezu danach, optisch vom Hauptsatz getrennt zu werden.

Alternative: Die beiden Gedankenstriche durch Klammern ersetzen.

> Dann stellte er sich hinter Baldini (der noch immer ...) und wartete,
> zitternd vor Ungeduld, dass der Alte sich entferne und ihm Platz mache.

Comment: Der Relativsatz nach *Baldini* endet aber erst nach *wartete*. Folglich müsste dieses Komma durch einen Gedankenstrich ersetzt werden.

Comment: Ich gebe zu, ich habe mich geirrt.